# ModuleNotFoundError for .vision and .utils , download_url, VisionDataset

Tags: google-colaboratory, torchvision

I am trying to create a custom dataset in google colab, but imports give me errors.

```py
from PIL import Image
from six.moves import zip
import os
from .vision import VisionDataset       ------------------------(1)
from .utils import download_url, check_integrity  --------------(2)

class datasetName(VisionDataset):
  ...
```

(1) error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.vision'; '**main**' is
>   not a package

(2) error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.utils'; '**main**' is
>   not a package

I have tried to add `from torchvision import utils` but it does not solve the error.

If I change to `from torch.utils import download_url, check_integrity` 
then the error becomes:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'download_url'

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following import lines.

```
from torchvision.datasets.vision import VisionDataset
from torchvision.datasets.utils import download_url, check_integrity
```

Hope it helps!